# SP SPUtility GetSPField not cosistant

Tags: sputility

I have a piece of code using SPUtility on the same page. I try both version on the same line:

version A result: Unable to get a SPField named FieldA

```
...
$(document).ready(function () {
    var SPFA = SPUtility.GetSPField('FieldA');
...
});
```

At first I suspect the SPUtility didn't load completely when the document.ready() run. so i try to change the document.ready() to window.load(), but it still not working.

I accidently use a SPUtility.HideSPField() function before this piece of code, and magically, it work! Why???

version B result: work fine.

```
...
SPUtility.HideSPField('FieldB'); //magic that make the code work?!
$(document).ready(function () {
    var SPFA = SPUtility.GetSPField('FieldA');
...
});
```

Anyone have any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: It's always worked for me. When you say it's not working, are you getting that as an error? Are you expecting the value in SPFA or the object?

Comment: On code version B, i get the SPField which i expected. But on the code version A, i did not get the SPField, it return "Unable to get a SPField named FieldA".

Answer (score 0):

The SPUtility file might not be loaded when the document is ready. You can try one of the following ways to execute the function always

```
$(window).load(function(){
//your code
});
```

or you can push your function to queue as follows

```
function myFunction(){
//your code
}
```

You can refer [this article](https://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation) for complete explanation